# Redis memorylimit with read-only

Tags: memory, redis, limit

I know about the main way, how Redis handles the key when memory limit is reached. However...

What if I want Redis to "lock down" it self by making it read-only till the point when some keys will receive a delete signal. The only reason is that all the data in our Redis Cluster are quite important, thus we wish to have them ready any time. But OFC, if the memory limit is reached, we need to save some space, but without losing any data decided by Redis, but rather by the user.

Example: 
User watches his statistic window on our applicatino server. Behind that, we store every data in Redis and display it for him. When the user closes the webapp, I'm currently freeing up all the keys related to his session. I want to drop these keys when a memory limit is reached, so noone should be getting "random" keys deleted or the least frequently used one neither.

Is this a possible thing or I'm just dreaming?

Comment: you may run "info memory" before setting something and make some comparison - put a buffer maybe. while setting the keys you may set a TTL to free up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`maxmemory-policy` determines how your cache behaves when it reaches maxmemory. The default option is `noeviction` which means it won't try to automatically evict any items based on TTL or LRU, etc. This essentially means the cache is then read-only, you can't add new items, but can still read existing items from it.

Obviously some external process or user will then need to delete some of the items, before you can add new data to it.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/5.0/redis.conf (search for MEMORY MANAGEMENT in that config file)